# react-native clean cache in xcode ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native-mixpanel in my app react-native v0.49.
when I compile it in android it works fine but in ios with xcode it shows me

```
ld: library not found for -lRNMixpanel-tvOS

    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so I decided to delete the plugin with commands:

```
react-native unlink react-native-mixpanel
npm uninstall react-native-mixpanel
```

then i run npm install again.

I don't see the plugin anymore in package.json.

in addition I delete any keyword in xcode settings with the word mixpanel but I still get the same error.

```
ld: library not found for -lRNMixpanel-tvOS
```

anyone to clean the cache or solve this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i hit some simillar issue a few days ago on RN 49.3, 
the problem was caused by some misplaced import (i'm not sure), 
and for how i solved, it was by removing the library from Build phase-> Link Binary with libraries

and for Cleaning cache in xcode the shortcut is (Cmd + k).